# Product custom attributes not updated - Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, magento2.3.4

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 CE. I used the below JSON to update the product custom attribute **part_number** in swagger.

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": 678899,
    "name": "Product name",
    "attribute_set_id": "4",
    "price": 2.93,
    "status": "1",
    "visibility": 0,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "weight": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "stock_item": {
        "qty": 10,
        "is_in_stock": true
      }
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "part_number",
        "value": "123456"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I get 200 success response but when I checked in **admin** and **catalog_product_entity_varchar** table I don't see the custom attribute **part_number** value updated.

I have checked with both PUT and POST method but it is not updated **part_number**

> PUT http://127.0.0.1/default/m234/rest/all/V1/products/678899
>
> POST http://127.0.0.1/default/m234/rest/all/V1/products

I have seen known issues https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4527 but I didn't see the proper solution.

Comment: have you found any solution on this

Answer (score 0):

Hello this works for me:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean`

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Updating-an-attribute-set-doesn-t-seem-to-work/td-p/126428